# Why webpack builds a bundle with lint errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint

"npm run lint" shows no errors in source code. But when I build main.js with webpack then it has a lot of issues.. Should main.js be excluded from linting when I commit my changes? Or how it can be fixed? Typical errors:

```
warning  Split initialized 'var' declarations into multiple statements        one-var
```

Here is my webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  devServer: {
    port: '3006',
    static: ['./public'],
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    liveReload: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser'
    }),
    new Dotenv()
  ]
};
```

Comment: Could you replicate the problem in a repo?

Comment: sorry.. I cannot share my repo. The issue is that lint fails on main.js but works fine on source code. So either main.js built wrong or I need to exclude it from linting

Comment: Running eslint on production bundle? May be I am missing smth, but does that make any sense at all?

Comment: I probably need to ignore prod bundle.. . But does it mean bundle built wrong way if LINT finds some issues?